# TypeError: this.gameWord is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write code for Hangman game whit objects, but I have a big problem; I wrote a class and I wanted to use in it  methods from another class.

The code is:

```
var Game = {
    // All game

    rightGuess : "",
    wrongGuess : "",
    gameWord : DisplaySecretWord.selectWord(),
    gameSecret : DisplaySecretWord.getSecretWord(),

    isLetterInWord : function(letter){
        var isRightGuess = false;

        for(i = 0; i < this.gameWord.length; i++)
        {
            if(letter == this.gameWord.substring(i, i + 1))
            {
                this.rightGuess += letter;
                this.gameSecret = this.gameSecret.substring(0, i) + letter + this.gameSecret.substring(i + 1, this.gameSecret.length + 1);
                DisplaySecretWord.dispayWord(this.gameSecret);
                var el = document.getElementById("right");
                if (el != null || el != undefined ){
                el.innerHTML = this.rightGuess;
            }
            isRightGuess = true;
            this.win();
            }


        }
        if(!isRightGuess)
        {
            this.wrongGuess += letter;
            var e = document.getElementById("wrong");
            if (e != null || e != undefined ){
            e.innerHTML = this.wrongGuess;
        }
            DisplayBoard.displayPic(this.wrongGuess);
            this.lose();
        }
    },
    win : function(){
        if(this.gameSecret == this.gameWord){
        alert("Good job!!! You win! The word was " + this.gameWord);
    }
    },
    lose : function(){
        if( this.wrongGuess.length == maxWrong){
        alert("Sorry but you lose!!! The word was " + this.gameWord + " .Click 'New Game' to play again!");
    }
    },

};
```

When I run my program I have:

> TypeError: this.gameWord is undefined
>
> line 87: for(i = 0; i < this.gameWord.length; i++)".I have "this"
>   before gameWord.

Why have a error?

Comment: How is it being initialized/called?

Comment: What if you try `Game.gameWord`?

Comment: i'm trying Game.isLetterInWord()

Comment: is Your method `DisplaySecretWord.selectWord()` realy return some word? Check before loop in `isLetterInWord` method, variable `gameWord` by putting it on console `console.log(this.gameWord)`;

Comment: Yes, DisplaySecretWord.selectWord(),i'm check it

Comment: I create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukaszewczak/7r45s/) with Your object and I execute `isLetterInWord` method and it works, as @epascarello wrote, put some code how it is being called

Comment: I had a mistake in  "Game" initialize,now everything works.Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it as:

```
this.setAttribute("gameWord","");
```

Then modify it as you want